# How to check orientation of each consecutive section?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a macro that would plot through currently opened document sections one by one, check whether they are portrait or landscape, and set their margins (incl. header and footer) to given dimensions (which are different depending on the page orientation).

How do I detect the page orientation of each section and make it the current "selection" or put the cursor on its beginning, so the next line could set its margins and skip to the next section?

This is what I got so far:

```
Sub Margins()
    Dim nOriginalPagination     As Integer
    Dim objSection              As Section
    Dim nPaperSize              As Integer
    Dim ContinueOn              As Boolean

    ContinueOn = False
    nNumSects = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPageView

    If ActiveWindow.View.SeekView <> wdSeekMainDocument Then
        ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    End If

    Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove

    For Each objSection In objDocument.Sections
        iSecNum = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
        With objSection.PageSetup
            nPaperSize = PAPERLETTER    
        End With
    Next

    For Each objSection In objDocument.Sections
        iSecNum = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
        With objSection.PageSetup
            'Set the margins, depending on the page orientation
            If .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
                .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
                .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
                .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.96)
                .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.94)
            Else
                .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
                .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
                .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)
                .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)
            End If
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Options.Pagination = nOriginalPagination

        Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToNext

    Next

End Sub
```

Error says I am missing as object.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821149.aspx

Comment: You should first show us what you tried. Have you read [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

- undeclared variables
- unnecessary use of the Selection object
- ScreenUpdating being turned on without having been turned off

The line that is causing the error is:

```
For Each objSection In objDocument.Sections
```

This is because the undeclared variable objDocument is not set to anything.
The code you need is below:

```
Sub Margins()
    Dim objDocument as Document
    Dim objSection As Section

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set objDocument = ActiveDocument
    For Each objSection In objDocument.Sections
        With objSection.PageSetup
            'Set the margins, depending on the page orientation
            If .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
                .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
                .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
                .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.96)
                .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.94)
            Else
                .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.17)
                .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.21)
                .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.23)
                .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)
                .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.9)
            End If
        End With
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```